# DateTime TryParseExact and padding

Tags: c#, .net, datetime

I'm calling `TryParse` on a string that I want to parse as a `DateTime`. Simple stuff. And it all works when the format is as I'd expect. But when each component/some of the components of the date are a single figure, the parse fails.

Example:

```
var dateFormat = "yyyy-dd-MM hh:mm:ss";
var dateString = "2006-4-1 2:3:5";

DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, dateFormat, 
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result)
```

If I change my `dateString` to `"2006-04-01 02:03:05"`, it parses fine.

### **Question**

How can I tell the parser to interpret `2` as `02` so that the above parses successfully?

### **What I've Tried**

Manually padding each part of the date time to ensure it fits the format. This works, but it doesn't feel very elegant. Is this the only way?

I've also tried, with no success, to use a format like `m` instead of `mm`.

Comment: Why not use TryParse instead of TryParseExact ? According to msdn (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131044(v=vs.110).aspx) your date format must match exactly with your date string for TryParseExact to work, so this is expected behaviour.

Comment: @auburg - that's a fair comment, but I thought `TryParseExact` was a way of providing a suggested format for the date. I don't want to leave it open to any ambiguity. For example, the months and days may be swapped around given the environment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use

```
 // please note single letters (d, M, h, m, s) whenever you allow single digits
 var dateFormat = "yyyy-d-M h:m:s";
```

And you'll get it:

```
var dateString = "2006-4-1 2:3:5";

DateTime.TryParseExact(dateString, dateFormat, 
                       CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, DateTimeStyles.None, out result)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply Dimitry. what would happen when '2' becomes '10' though? This will work fine for 2nd hour, but fail for 10th hour?

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ: it'll be OK: *single* letters allow *single digit* numbers (as well two digit ones: `1`, `01`, `22` etc.)

Answer (score 1):

With regular expression:

```
int[] n = new Regex("[^0-9]+").Split("2006-4-1 2:3:5").Select(int.Parse).ToArray();
var datetime = new DateTime(n[0], n[1], n[2], n[3], n[4], n[5]);
```

Comment: It may allow *too many inputs* like `"2016 year? 4 month? 1 and 2 * 2 = 4"` - technically, the string contains *6 numbers*, but it's not a valid date.

Comment: Personaly, I'm not a fan using regex with DateTime parsing operations or generate their values. Because other than digits, the string _might_ generate day name, month name or AM/PM designators etc..